# Draw only visible shapes

Tags: c++, directx, clipping, direct2d

I'm developing a 2D graphics viewer by using `Direct2D`. I have a lot (up to 200,000) of shapes to draw. I would like to be able to draw only those shapes that are actually visible inside my canvas.

So, for example, if my window is 640x480 (starting from 0,0) I don't need to draw a rectangle which has its top-left corner in (1000, 1000).

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: @lightandlight For each shape I check if its bounds overlap the visible area. Can this help you in any way?

Comment: Don't draw the object if it isn't in the window (as determined by your checking function).

Comment: @lightandlight Too slow. Your hint (that is my solution) is useless.

Comment: Divide your virtual screen into a number of regions (they should be large enough to fully contain "most" of your objects entirely). On drawing, check which of these *regions* are visible. If fully visible, draw everything inside it; else, decide per object.

Comment: You already have a solution to the question that you actually wrote, so what is your real question? Just that it's not fast enough? Well, profile your code to find out where you waste your time. That said, consider two alternative approaches: The first is to do the drawing in a background thread, which leaves your UI responsive (in case that is your unstated goal). The second alternative approach is to delegate rendering to the hardware, which might involve switching to a 3D framework though, even if you don't use one dimension.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What are the main difference between Direct2D and the 3D framework you are proposing? Which framework exactly (DirectX, OpenGL)? Do you have any reference?

Comment: A 2D-framework is restricted to two dimensions (i.e. a plane), while a 3D-framework allows three dimensions. Concerning the framework, I used Open Scenegraph last time, but that is not necessarily relevant for you. Still, question remains what your problem is. Up to now, I'm voting to close your question because it is unclear.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If the only difference is the number of dimensions your hint is useless. If you read carefully my bottleneck is the rendering part, therefore the need to draw only the visible shapes. The question cannot be more clear.

Comment: No, it may not be entirely useless, because 3D frameworks must(!) avoid rendering invisible things, so they contain this feature by default and are optimized(!) for that. Further, you already skip all shapes that don't have to be rendered, but you are still asking how to do that. Maybe the way to determine whether something needs to be drawn is too slow, but there is neither code nor actual timings you provide. Maybe the amount of data just requires a lot of time. In summary, your problem remains unclear.

Comment: @Nick What is your drawing cycle rate? Have you figured out if your program is CPU-bound or GPU-bound?

Comment: @AntonAngelov How can I figure out if my program is CPU-bound or GPU-bound?

Comment: You **need** to use direct3d and vertex buffer for the shapes. It is the fastest way to be done without checking for the clipping, it is a free gift.

Comment: This is the very basic functionality of all the windowing GUI/graphics system. Nothing special. Check boundary, check z-order. If it's not enough, you must did something wrong. (It was not special even in Windows 3.1 era)